# appending a list from a read text file python3

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am attempting to read a txt file and create a dictionary from the text.  a sample txt file is:

```
John likes Steak

John likes Soda

John likes Cake

Jane likes Soda

Jane likes Cake

Jim likes Steak
```

My desired output is a dictionary with the name as the key, and the "likes" as a list of the respective values:

```
{'John':('Steak', 'Soda', 'Cake'), 'Jane':('Soda', 'Cake'), 'Jim':('Steak')}
```

I continue to run into the error of adding my stripped word to my list and have tried a few different ways:

```
pred = ()

prey = ()

spacedLine = inf.readline()

line = spacedLine.rstrip('\n')

while line!= "":

    line = line.split()
    pred.append = (line[0])
    prey.append = (line[2])
    spacedLine = inf.readline()
    line = spacedLine.rstrip('\n')
```

and also:

spacedLine = inf.readline()

```
line = spacedLine.rstrip('\n')

while line!= "":

     line = line.split()      
     if line[0] in chain:
       chain[line[0] = [0, line[2]]
      else:
        chain[line[0]] = line[2]
    spacedLine = inf.readline()
    line = spacedLine.rstrip('\n')
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dic={}

for i in f.readlines():
    if i:
        if i.split()[0] in dic.keys():
            dic[i.split()[0]].append(i.split()[2])
        else:
            dic[i.split()[0]]=[i.split()[2]]

print dic
```

This should do it.

Here we iterater through `f.readlines` `f` being the file object,and on each line we fill up the dictionary by using first part of split as key and last part of split as value

Comment: This is like words of a Zen master: while completely correct and even probably wise, these are opaque for the one who asked the question, and will require long and intense meditation over the three lines to get their true meaning.

Comment: This seems very close, but still only returns one key : one value
i get:
{'John':'Cake', 'Jane':'Cake', 'Jim':'Steak'}
It is overwriting my val instead of adding to it.

Comment: This seems very close, but still only returns {one key : one value}, not {one key : multiple values}

i get:

{'John':'Cake', 'Jane':'Cake', 'Jim':'Steak'}
It is overwriting my val instead of adding to it and I am back to where I started.

Comment: my list index is out of range.  im a geologist, not a comp sci student....my understanding is very limited.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it (without needing to read the entire file into memory first):

```
likes = {}
for who, _, what in (line.split()
                        for line in (line.strip()
                            for line in open('likes.txt', 'rt'))):
    likes.setdefault(who, []).append(what)

print(likes)
```

Output:

```
{'Jane': ['Soda', 'Cake'], 'John': ['Steak', 'Soda', 'Cake'], 'Jim': ['Steak']}
```

Alternatively, to simplify things slightly you could use a temporary`collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

likes = defaultdict(list)
for who, _, what in (line.split()
                        for line in (line.strip()
                            for line in open('likes.txt', 'rt'))):
    likes[who].append(what)

print(dict(likes))  # convert to plain dictionary and print
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input is a sequence of sequences. Parse the outer sequence first, parse each item next.

Your outer sequence is:

```
Statement
<empty line>
Statement
<empty line>
...
```

Assume that `f` is the open file with the data. Read each statement and return a list of them:

```
def parseLines(f):
  result = []
  for line in f:  # file objects iterate over text lines
    if line:  # line is non-empty
      result.append(line)
  return result
```

Note that the function above accepts a much wider grammar: it allows arbitrarily many empty lines between non-empty lines, and two non-empty lines in a row. But it does accept any correct input.

Then, your statement is a triple: `X likes Y`. Parse it by splitting it by whitespace, and checking the structure. The result is a correct pair of `(x, y)`.

```
def parseStatement(s):
  parts = s.split()  # by default, it splits by all whitespace
  assert len(parts) == 3, "Syntax error: %r is not three words" % s
  x, likes, y = parts  # unpack the list of 3 items into varaibles
  assert likes == "likes", "Syntax error: %r instead of 'likes'" % likes
  return x, y
```

Make a list of pairs for each statement:

```
pairs = [parseStatement(s) for s in parseLines(f)]
```

Now you need to group values by key. Let's use `defaultdict` which supplies a default value for any new key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

the_answer = defaultdict(list)  # the default value is an empty list

for key, value in pairs:
  the_answer[key].append(value) 
  # we can append because the_answer[key] is set to an empty list on first access
```

So here `the_answer` is what you need, only it uses lists as dict values instead of tuples. This must be enough for you to understand your homework.